# Мобильное приложение на HTML5

Tags: html5, mobile, mobile-web

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сделать мобильное приложение ( не важно хорошее или нет ) на HTML5 ? 
Задаюсь таким вопросом, потому что наткнулся на некую книгу и был в удивлении.
Если можно, то какие попутные технологии так же нужны для создания моб. приложения?

Comment: Пишешь html страницу для смартфона, потом просто её отображаешь с помощью элемента webview, буквально в несколько строчек. По желанию, можно с легкостью создать интерфейс между функциями java и js на твоей странице, и пользоваться всеми возможностями андроид

Comment: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/web-view